# How to get values of DataGridView.Rows.Columns from Form 2 to Form 1

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

- DataGridView - Placed in Form - 2
- TextBox1 - Placed in Form - 1

I want to access Data Grid View Row and Column value in Form - 1 and display in textbox.

I'm writing this code below:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
DataGridView data = new DataGridView();
data = form2.qualitySetupDataGridView;

MessageBox.Show(data.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
```

***Error Message:*** Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Note: DataGridView Modifiers is set to public. I have 3-4 Records in the DataGridView that is placed in form-2.

Comment: Is that code in the Form1 source? Does it mean you are instantiating Form2 from Form1?

Comment: You are making an new instance of Form2 in your Form1, thus having an empty DatagridView. You should pass the current instance of DatagridView on your Form1 when you open it in Form2

Comment: @JCabello Thats correct.

Comment: @apomene: code will be appreciated. 

I'm thinking form2.qualitySetupDataGridView is doing the job. so its empty datagridview no wonder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making an new instance of Form2 in your Form1, thus having an empty DatagridView. You should pass the current instance of DatagridView , e.g:

Form1:

Fawad Edited:

You forgot to create object: this does the job, but it pops up form 2 for a second to get data and then recloses, which isn't perfect but gets the job done.

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
Form2.Show();
Form2.Hide();

Form2 f = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form2>().ElementAt<Form2>(0); //Get current open Form2
DataGridView data = f.qualitySetupDataGridView;
MessageBox.Show(data.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
```

Comment: after writing this code, now I'm getting a different error. 

**System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of range of valid values. Parameter: Index.**

Comment: is there any open Form2??is there a datagridVIew in Form2 instatinated?

Comment: just 1 here. this is in form - 1

`private void qualitySetupToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Quality Setup Form Goes here.
       

            // This updates ComboBox Value with new-Added Data in Quality Setup.
            new Form2().ShowDialog();
            this.qualitySetupTableAdapter.Fill(this.setupsDBDataSet.QualitySetup);
            this.comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;

        }`

Comment: I got your point.

by doing this 
`Form2 form2 = new Form();
DataGridView data = new DataGrid View;
data = form2.qualitySetupDataGridView;`

I'm creating a new empty form and linking a new empty datagridview.


However my debugger is throwing exception at this line:
`Form2 f = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form2>().ElementAt<Form2>(0);`

Comment: Just for your information: I have 3 forms, but form 3 is doing nothing basically just pops up help and displays application information.

Comment: I guess the elementAt(0) index is incorrect for form 2 in my case.

Comment: elementAt(0) indicates the first instance of Form2, if no Form2 is opened then you get an out of bounds exception

Comment: Yep Form 2 isn't opened. 
I just need Data from DataGridView that is in form 2 in form1

Comment: How will you get data from an object that does not exist. 1st you have to open Form2, bind the data you want to grid and then call Form2 grid from Form1 as indicated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71247/discussion-between-fawad-and-apomene).